# Response.Redirect not working as expected - page refreshes itself, no redirect occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

So, I'm trying to have a field in a gridview which is a link that opens a details page, based on the row clicked.   The details page works when I go to it manually, but I can't seem to access it via calling a function which does a Response.Redirect(URL) - instead, I get the odd behavior that when the linkbutton is clicked, the page does a postback and stays on itself.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using Server.Transfer() instead?  I'd rather use redirect, because having the url update seems to me like an interface advantage in the use case I'm looking at.

This is part of a sharepoint webpart, the other page is on the same sharepoint server, and is a different collection of webparts.

```
<asp:Gridview ID="grdWU" runat="server" [+bunch of settings]>
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Workunit #" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"> 
      <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:Linkbutton ID="Workunit" runat="server" **OnClientClick="OpenDetails"** Text='<%# Bind("Workunit") %>'></asp:Linkbutton>
      </ItemTemplate> 
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

In the code behind class:

```
    protected void OpenDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton) sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Button btnWorkunit = (Button)clickedRow.FindControl("Workunit");
          //Response.Redirect(workunitdetailsurl + "?Workunit=" + activeworkunit.ID, true);
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Out of desperation/diagnosis, I tried to redirect to google instead of my crafted URL... still nothing.  The page only refreshes itself.  Am I doing something wrong?

Post-answer Edit: I guess I wasn't properly understanding the difference between onclick and onclientclick.

Comment: Why are you doing it onclientclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been able to confirm your event is actually firing?  Try using the `OnClick` event of the LinkButton instead of `OnClientClick`.

Also, try using the second overload for `Response.Redirect` which accepts a boolean indicating to end the execution of the current page:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true); //Indicates that the execution of the current page should terminate.
```

Comment: I updated my response to suggest using `OnClick` on your linkbutton instead of `OnClientClick`

Comment: When I use OnClick I get -
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.
Going to look further at linkbuttons... I was under the impression they behaved more like a Button than this...

Comment: update the line in your event that is casting the control: `LinkButton btnWorkunit = (LinkButton)clickedRow.FindControl("Workunit");`

Comment: Yeah, oops.  I did that, but felt exceptionally dumb.  Now I'm just commenting them out until I can at least get the page to redirect to google.

Edit: And there is glorious victory.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect throws ThreadAbortException... try to handle the exception and also you can try html controls like input button or hyperlinks rather than link button in item template..